# Looking for a Highmaps example of worldmap with GPS coordinates

Tags: highmaps

Looking for a Highmaps example of world map with GPS coordinates.
Searched docs and google and no luck.

The idea is to set a LAT LNG array of points and display all points across the Highcharts map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load proj4js before Highmaps, for example from [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/proj4js) like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.12/proj4-src.js"></script>
```

Then when creating your series you give each point a `lat` and a `lon`, like this:

```
series: [{
    data: [{
        name: 'London',
        lat: 51.507222,
        lon: -0.1275
    }]
}]
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dnbtkmyz/) and [this more comprehensive lat/lng documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/latlon).